# Assembler packing data

Tags: assembly, x86, inline-assembly

I need write assebler code for write 3 letter's word in minimal cell memory
this picture, that illustrated what I need:

[image]

I'm starting writing code:

```
    mov eax, dword ptr str[0]
    bsr cl, eax
    inc cl
    shl eax, cl
    push eax
    //
    mov eax, dword ptr str[1]
    pop ebx
    or eax, ebx
    push eax // unshifted
    //
    mov eax, dword ptr str[2]
    bsr cl, eax
    inc cl
    pop ebx
    shl ebx, cl
    or eax, ebx
    mov result, ebx
```

But I get -934608896 (‭00110111101101010000000000000000‬ after negate)
instead of 1304526 (0100111110011111001110)

Comment: so, why don't you check values in registers after each single instruction, where the calculation diverts from your expectations? Just final result doesn't tell much, what was going on. ( http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/ )

Comment: But on the picture.. it's a bit unusual to have bits going from 0 to 31 left-to-right, usually b0 is "first/bottom/least_significant" bit, which has value 1 (0th power of 2). Then shift "left" is moving bit toward b31 "up" (from b0 into b1, etc...), i.e. multiplying by 2, and shift "right" is moving bit toward b0 ("down"), i.e. "almost dividing by 2". Do you have those labels going in non-standard way on purpose?  (i.e. value 0x14 is in binary 0001_0100 ... from left to right b7 to b0 and shl 0x14,1 = 0x28)

Answer (score 5):

The result is in `EAX` after the final `or eax, ebx`.
Why do you put `EBX` in *result*? Is this the wrong value that you inspect?

This is a code that inserts 3 bitpatterns in the same register:

```
movzx eax, byte ptr str[0]
movzx ebx, byte ptr str[1]
bsr   ecx, ebx
inc   ecx
shl   eax, cl
or    eax, ebx
movzx ebx, byte ptr str[2]
bsr   ecx, ebx
inc   ecx
shl   eax, cl
or    eax, ebx
mov   result, eax
```